# My application is crashing using Do/While loop to parse table

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, crash, do-while

I have 2 QCheckbox tables, each contains 11 elements.
I declare them as following in my class :

```
QCheckBox *sectionTable[10];
QCheckBox *postTable[10];
```

For each QCheckBox, I do this

```
QCheckBox* checkboxA = new QCheckBox("A");
sectionTable[0] = checkboxA;
```

Through my test method, I would like to return the content of each element of my QCheckbox tables.
To do so, I've done this test :

```
/** TEST() **/
void VGCCC::test()
{
    sectionTable[0]->setText("A");
    sectionTable[1]->setText("B");
    sectionTable[2]->setText("C");
    sectionTable[3]->setText("D");
    postTable[0]->setText("E");
    postTable[1]->setText("F");
    postTable[2]->setText("G");
    postTable[3]->setText("H");

    int i=0;
    do
    {
        m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText(sectionTable[i]->text());
        std::cout << "SECTION TABLE " << sectionTable[i]->text().toStdString() << "\n" << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    while(!sectionTable[i]->text().isNull());

    do
    {
        m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText(postTable[i]->text());
        std::cout << "POST TABLE " << postTable[i]->text().toStdString() << "\n" << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    while(!postTable[i]->text().isEmpty());
}
```

My application is compiling, and also running. But when I call the test function, my application crash.

How can we explain this problem ?

I would like to notify that I get a result in my console. It seems my test is half working, but is crashing at the end of the 1st do/while loop, when I get out of my condition.

[image: Console Output]

Comment: Not enough code has been provided for a definitive answer, but `QCheckBox *sectionTable[10];` allocates an array of pointers to `QCheckBox`. `sectionTable[0]->setText("A");` tries to use a `QCheckBox` assigned to one of those pointers, but did you ever create and assign a `QCheckBox`? That code is missing.

Comment: @user4581301 I assign a QCheckBox as following : `QCheckBox* checkboxA = new QCheckBox("A");
sectionTable[0] = checkboxA;` . I have to precise that my tables can contain 11 QCheckbox elements, but I didn't fill it entirely in purpose.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to the 11 elements: `QCheckBox *sectionTable[10];` defines only 10 slots (0 through 9) for elements.

```
int i=0;
do
{
    m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText(sectionTable[i]->text());
    std::cout << "SECTION TABLE " << sectionTable[i]->text().toStdString() << "\n" << std::endl;
    i++;
}
while(!sectionTable[i]->text().isNull());
```

Has the potential to reach past ten or eleven elements. Unless the terminating condition is found earlier, there is nothing to stop `sectionTable[i]` from trying to read `sectionTable[11]` to call its `text` method. If it manages to survive the call to the out-of-range `sectionTable[11]->text()`, it will then try calling `sectionTable[11]->text().isNull()`. Possibly this will be survivable as well and not be NULL. In this case `sectionTable[12]` will be tested. This will continue until the program hits really bad memory and crashes, a null is found, or pigs become the terror of the airways we all know they truly wish to be.

Note that `i` is not set back to 0 after this loop, so the first `postTable` to be inspected in the next loop will be at the same index as the last `sectionTable`.

So if `sectionTable[5]->text().isNull()` was NULL, `postTable[5]` will be the first `postTable` indexed and inspected.

```
do
{
    m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText(postTable[i]->text());
    std::cout << "POST TABLE " << postTable[i]->text().toStdString() << "\n" << std::endl;
    i++;
}
while(!postTable[i]->text().isEmpty());
```

This loop has the same error in the exit condition as the `sectionTable` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I find out how to solve the problem. As said in the answer before (@user4581301), I didn't set back my iterator i to 0.
Also, to avoid the "out of range" crash, I put a second condition which is `i<sizeof(sectionTable[i]);`

This is my fonctional test function :

```
/** TEST() **/
void VGCCC::test()
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText(sectionTable[i]->text());
        std::cout << "SECTION TABLE " << m_materialMap[sectionTable[i]].c_str() << "\n" << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    while(!sectionTable[i]->text().isNull() && i<sizeof(sectionTable[i]));

    i = 0;
    do
    {
        m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText(postTable[i]->text());
        std::cout << "POST TABLE " << postTable[i]->text().toStdString() << "\n" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "POST TABLE " << m_materialMap[postTable[i]].c_str() << "\n" << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    while(!postTable[i]->text().isEmpty() && i<sizeof(postTable[i]));
}
```

Comment: Danger: `sizeof(sectionTable[i])` will return the size of one element of `sectionTable`. The index does not matter as all elements are the same size. Since this is a pointer, the size will be the size of a pointer (probably be 4 or 8), not  the count of elements in the array. To get the element count, you need  `sizeof(sectionTable)/sizeof(sectionTable[0])`. From an engineering standpoint defining `QCheckBox *sectionTable[SIZE_OF_TABLE];` and then `while(!sectionTable[i]->text().isNull() && i<SIZE_OF_TABLE)` may be better as it's easier to read.